# Non-TCP listener in Elastic Beanstalk with Network Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS question time. I'm using an Elastic Beanstalk (EB) environment with a Network Load Balancer (NLB), and trying to create a UDP listener via boto3 python library. I know that NLB supports it, but EB apparently not as per [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbv2-listener-default).

Regardless, I'm stubborn and tried adding the following to `OptionSettings` when creating/updating the environment, according to the same docs:

```
[
  {
    'Namespace': 'aws:elbv2:listener:5060',
    'OptionName': 'Protocol',
    'Value': 'UDP'
  },
  {
    'Namespace': 'aws:elbv2:listener:5060',
    'OptionName': 'ListenerEnabled',
    'Value': 'true'
  },
  {
    'Namespace': 'aws:elbv2:listener:5060',
    'OptionName': 'DefaultProcess',
    'Value': 'udp'
  },
  {
    'Namespace': 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:udp',
    'OptionName': 'Protocol',
    'Value': 'UDP'
  },
  {
    'Namespace': 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:udp',
    'OptionName': 'Port',
    'Value': '5060'
  }
]
```

Which got me:

```
Invalid option value: 'UDP' (Namespace: 'aws:elbv2:listener:5060', OptionName: 'Protocol'): Only TCP Protocols are supported for Network Load Balancers.
```

I then tried using a config file under `.ebextensions` folder similar to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html), but creating a target group and listener with UDP protocol. I thought this would go straight to Cloud Formation (CF) and bypass EB limitations, but I got the exact same error as above which makes me think that it translated the CF template in the config file into EB option settings (sigh).

The last option is to bypass EB completely and go straight to the load balancer. This approach has some issues I would like to avoid, so is there another way to use non-TCP listeners in EB?

Comment: If you use `Resources` you can inspect resulting template in CFN console.

Comment: @Hossomi have you find a workaround for this?

Comment: @pars Unfortunately not. Ultimately I gave up EB and moved to CF.